# Define relationship to tables as a whole

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to define a table which basically will contain an Id for a user, and a second column which will list names of tables to which the user has access. I can't think of anyway to define any relationships here in case the original table names change. All the logic will be at the application level. However, I would like to be able to define some sort of constraints. How can I do this? Also, I am open to advice regarding any other way to do this.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Table renaming should be a rare enough event so that the scenario would not be a problem in itself. Anyway, the DB change script could rename the table and update the existing data to the new name.

Comment: Anyway, if you simply are defining permissions per table, it's much better to use the build-in security system of SQL Server instead of replicating it in the client. Application-level permissions are usually not indicated by table name, but by user action.

Comment: Are users actually SQL Server Logins or they are just records in your table?

Comment: there are no sql server logins. these are just records in my table. I guess what I'm asking is if there's a better way to do this schema-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I am really confused.  Doesn't the [`grant`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) command do *exactly* what you want?  This assumes that the operations you want are database operations.

If you have a more customized set of operations, then you can keep track of table name changes via [DDL triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: This is a good solution, unless the users are NOT SQL Server Logins, in which case this probably won't work

Comment: @sallushan . . . Or Windows user logins, which considerably expands the utility.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a detailed code example of how to achieve this using RLS

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.OKTable
(
    OKTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_OKTable PRIMARY KEY,
    SecuredInfo varchar(100)
);
GO

INSERT dbo.OKTable (SecuredInfo)
VALUES ('Very'), ('Secret'), ('Stuff');
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.NotOKTable
(
    NotOKTableID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_NotOKTable PRIMARY KEY,
    SecuredInfo varchar(100)
);
GO

INSERT dbo.NotOKTable (SecuredInfo)
VALUES ('Other'), ('Important'), ('Things');
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [Security] AUTHORIZATION dbo;
GO

CREATE TABLE [Security].PermittedTableUsers
(
    PermittedTableUsers int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Security_PermittedTableUsers 
        PRIMARY KEY,
    UserName sysname,
    SchemaName sysname,
    TableName sysname
);
GO

INSERT [Security].PermittedTableUsers (UserName, SchemaName, TableName)
VALUES (N'dbo', N'dbo', 'OKTable');
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [Security].CheckUserAccess
(
    @SchemaName AS sysname,
    @TableName AS sysname
)  
RETURNS TABLE  
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
    RETURN SELECT 1 AS CheckUserAccessOutcome
           WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Security].PermittedTableUsers AS ptu
                                  WHERE ptu.UserName = USER_NAME()
                                  AND ptu.SchemaName = @SchemaName
                                  AND ptu.TableName = @TableName);
GO

CREATE SECURITY POLICY OKTableAccessFilter 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE [Security].CheckUserAccess (N'dbo', N'OKTable')
ON dbo.OKTable  
WITH (STATE = ON); 
GO
CREATE SECURITY POLICY NotOKTableAccessFilter 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE [Security].CheckUserAccess (N'dbo', N'NotOKTable')
ON dbo.NotOKTable  
WITH (STATE = ON); 
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.OKTable;
SELECT * FROM dbo.NotOKTable;
GO
```

It's described more fully in this link:

https://blog.greglow.com/2019/10/10/sql-how-to-control-access-to-sql-server-tables-by-entries-in-another-table/

Comment: I presumed you have a reason for doing it this way, but otherwise, have to agree with Gordon that GRANT/DENY/REVOKE is built-in functionality that is far preferable. The RLS option though, has two potential benefits. The first is that no error is thrown i.e. you just don't see the data. And second, this would allow you to extend this to finer-grained control.

Answer (score 0):

Since users are NOT SQL Server Logins, therefore, I guess you can use the DDL trigger to monitor table rename where you can change the table name in your custom security table. But I don't know if you can throw exception within this trigger to prevent table rename (simulating some type of constraint). Also it would be better if you store the table name in each line rather saving comma separated table names in 1 field.

If you can utilize SQL Logins then the Gordan's solution is also applicable, but sometimes you cannot create SQL Logins, in-case if you have different application databases along with hundreds of thousands of users.